# How do I sum a list with its previous entries and substitute with new and corrected entries?

Tags: python, list, graph, sum, iteration

I am graphing the internet connection in my apartment, and I have data for upload and download speeds, and time with it aswell. I have a list of data for all these variables, but I need to sum my time list together with itself; that is, I need [a, a+b, a+b+c, a+b+c+d, a+b+c+d+e, ...] and so on.

My list with time only comes in intervals between 10 and 20 seconds, I need a way to sum them together and make a list as shown, is there an easy way to do this?

I've tried to iterate with a while loop without luck. I don't have the knowledge to come up with clever ideas, I'm new to Python.

iHaveThisList = ['a','b','c','d','e']    <-- They are still defined to be string variables.

iNeedThisList = [a, a+b, a+b+c, a+b+c+d, a+b+c+d+e]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work? (not the most efficient, I agree)

```
def cumsum(values):
    return [sum(values[:i]) for i in range(1, len(values))]
```

more efficient with generators:

```
def cumsum(values):
    s = 0
    for x in values:
        s += x
        yield s

# To get a list
cumulative = list(cumsum(values))
```